# Trimming the bottom of canvas, converting to escpos command and appending the a cut command results in premature cut

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas, escpos

I have written a function that takes a canvas scans the horizontal pixel rows from bottom to top to find all the empty lines and trims the canvas height. After trimming I scan through the image data and read pixels into packed bytes representing monochrome image where each bit is a pixel. Afterwards I make a large buffer and at the start put some prefix bytes found in the escpos docs. and at the end of the large buffer I am appending 3 bytes for a cut command.

If I remove the `epmtyLines` calculation part, everything works smoothly but as soon as I enable the line trimming logic. The printer actually prints the whole image and but the cut happens 70 to 80 horizontal rows before the end of image. I have reread the trimming logic dozens of times and nothing seems to be wrong.

Note: I am considering the last line of canvas to be empty by default hence starting the loop from `height - 2`.

```js
const canvasToEscpos = (canvas) => {
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const { data } = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  let width = canvas.width;
  let height = canvas.height;

  let emptyLines = 0;
  for (let y = height - 2; y >= 0; y--) {
    let empty = true;
    for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      empty &&= data[(width * y + x) * 4] > 248;
      if (!empty) break;
    }
    if (empty) {
      emptyLines++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  console.log({ emptyLines });
  height -= emptyLines + 1;

  const bytes = new Uint8Array((width * height) >> 3);
  const readPixel = (x, y) => {
    return data[(width * y + x) * 4] < 200 ? 1 : 0;
  };
  for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < width; x += 8) {
      for (let b = 0; b < 8; b++) {
        bytes[y * (width >> 3) + (x >> 3)] |= readPixel(x + b, y) << (7 - b);
      }
    }
  }
  const buffer = new Uint8Array(10 + bytes.length + 3);
  // image command
  buffer.set(
    [
      0x0a,
      0x0d,
      0x1d,
      0x76,
      0x30,
      0x00,
      (width >> 3) & 0xff,
      ((width >> 3) >> 8) & 0xff,
      height & 0xff,
      (height >> 8) & 0xff,
    ],
    0
  );
  // image bits
  buffer.set(bytes, 10);
  // cut
  buffer.set([0x1d, 0x56, 0x00], buffer.length - 3);
  return buffer;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is a gap between the print head of the printer and the paper cutter, if the paper is cut immediately after printing, the printed result will remain on the cut paper for that gap.
[GS V](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=87)

> ```
> [Name]
>   Select cut mode and cut paper
> [Format]
>   <Function A> ASCII   GS  V m
>                Hex     1D 56 m
>                Decimal 29 86 m
>   <Function B> ASCII   GS  V m n
>                Hex     1D 56 m n
>                Decimal 29 86 m n
>
>   <Function A> Cuts the paper                 0, 48 Full cut
>                                               1, 49 Partial cut
>   <Function B> Feeds paper and cuts the paper 65    Full cut
>                                               66    Partial cut
>
>   <Function A> Executes paper cut
>   <Function B> Feeds paper to [cutting position + (n × vertical motion unit)] and executes paper cut
> ```

Your program uses the `Function A` command on this page to cut the paper, but in order to include all the print results on the cut side, use the `Function B` command to set the paper feed amount before cutting to the printer. must be adjusted accordingly.

The distance between the printer's print head and the paper cutter may be different for each printer model, so check the specifications of your printer or adjust it by experiment.

For example, here is an example of paper cutting using EPSON's print data send tool.
[Select Cut Mode and Cut Paper](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=273)

Comment: Wow didnt even think of the difference between printing and cutter head. Anothre sorta related question about Function A. The m value for Function A is listed as 0, 48 for full cut. Does that mean 0 or 48 or does it mean anything between 0 an 48 inclusive?

Comment: It is one of two, 0 and 48 (=0x30).

Comment: If you could add one more bit of info I would really appreciate it. Your solution works great but now after one print the subsequent print gets messed up. Do I need to append some sort of reset command. It seems to print all the lines on top of each other. I do have a newline command ` 0x0a 0x0d` at the very beginning of each print.

Comment: I haven't dealt with JavaScript related stuff, so I haven't seen the details of your program. Therefore, the following can be considered as common things or impressions. When you create bit image print command data from canvas, or when you have a function such as setting the number of line feed units at the time of printing, there is something wrong or you have not set something that needs to be initialized isn't it?

Comment: Tried the same code on other printer and it works flawlessly so the natural conclusion is that issue is with the printer but my spider senses tell me still there is chance that I am doing something wrong. Maybe this will be a clue. When I send the same print over and over again. It prints and cuts fine the first 2 times the 3rd time the cut and print is mangled then I pull out the bad part and resend the print and then it again works 2 times and so on.